# What is 1,530 a reference to?

Tags: number, tanach, commentaries

In his commentary to Genesis 7:12, [R. Isaiah of Trani (the Elder)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaiah_di_Trani) writes:

> וכן במניין ישראל אלף וחמש מאות ושלשים ואי אפשר דבר זה שלא היה אחד מהם יתר או חסר אלא כן דרך המקראות לתפוש מניין שלם ואפי' חסר או יתר ב' אינו מקפיד
>
> And similarly with the number of Israel 1,530 – it is impossible this thing that not one of them was more or less. Rather, this is the way of Scripture to grasp a complete number, and not care even if it is less or more by two.

Is this 1,530 a reference to a specific verse where this number appears?

In a footnote in the Mossad Harav Kook edition [R. Charles Chavel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Ber_Chavel) writes:

> לא מצאתי פסוק זה
>
> I have not found this verse.

So is there such a verse? If yes, what verse is it? If no, what is R. Isaiah referencing?

Comment: maybe a mistake for [60]1730 in **אֵלֶּה, פְּקוּדֵי בְּנֵי יִשְׂרָאֵל--שֵׁשׁ-מֵאוֹת אֶלֶף, **וָאָלֶף; שְׁבַע מֵאוֹת, וּשְׁלֹשִׁים [

Comment: For what it's worth, the quoted commentary is also brought in [Chaim Yosef David Azulai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaim_Yosef_David_Azulai)'s [Penei David (on Parashat No'ach)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Penei_David%2C_Genesis%2C_Noach.6.2?lang=he) (also [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40237&pgnum=19), or [here](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01917.html#HtmpReportNum0004_L2)).